# Know that a specific scene is loaded or not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I know that a particular scene has already loaded so that I don't load it again. I am trying it through particular object (Of the loaded scene) search but its not working. The scene working in don't destroy on load fashion.

```
if (GameObject.Find("TA") == null)
{
    Debug.Log("TA Loaded");
    SceneManager.LoadScene("TA", LoadSceneMode.Additive);        
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify 'has already loaded'? Are you using additive scene loading?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i)` method, where `i` is the index.

Use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCount; i++) {
    Scene scene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i);
    if (!(scene.name == "YourSceneName" && scene.isLoaded)) {
        // Load your new scene
    }
}
```